# Static vs dynamic allocation of a pointer which stores just one int

Tags: c++, pointers

I wonder why I would need the second version?

```
int* p; // version 1
int* p = new int; // version 2
```

Comment: You are not allocating a pointer dynamically, but an `int`. The first version is an uninitialized pointer, the second is a pointer initialized to the address returned by the new expression. The first is useless (even reading the value of `p` is undefined behavior), the second isn't.

Comment: Why would you need the first version?

Comment: @juanchopanza: maybe at file scope? Not that mutable globals are a brilliant plan either, of course, if you can avoid them.

Comment: @SteveJessop Or as a data member, or in 1000 other situations too. My point is there isn't enough information to answer this without guessing. If OP just needs a pointer to point to something else later on, then they don't need the second version. If they want to de-reference then they *may* do. But maybe not...

Answer (score 2):

In the first version, the pointer isn't pointing at anything, it is undefined. Version 2 allocated memory and points p to that new memory. You are not allocating space for the pointer itself but memory for the pointer to point at. (In both versions the pointer itself is on  the stack)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code appears in a function:

The first one defines a local variable of type `int*` (that is, a pointer). The variable is not initialized, which means the pointer doesn't have a value. It doesn't point at anything. It's nearly useless, about the only thing you can do with it is assign a pointer value to it[*]. So you think to yourself, "can I hold off defining the variable until I have a value to assign to it?"

The second one defines a local variable of type `int*` (that is a pointer), and also dynamically allocates an object of type `int` and assigns the address of that object to the pointer variable. So the pointer points to the `int`.

Dynamically allocating one `int` is nearly always a bad idea. It's not *useless* in the sense that you do at least have an `int` and a means to access it. But you've created a problem for yourself in that you have to keep track of it and free it.

[*] other things you can do with an uninitialized `int*` variable: take the address of the variable; bind it to a reference of type `int*&`; convert the address of the variable to `char*` and examine the memory one byte at a time, just to see what your implementation has put in that uninitialized variable. Nothing exciting and, crucially, nothing involving any `int` objects because you have none.

Answer (score 0):

#### The first pointer

The first pointer, declared as:

```
int* p;
```

only allocates the memory needed to to store a pointer to `int`. The actual size is implementation defined. What the `p` object contains is *indeterminate* as per 8.5/12:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced (5.17).

This means that dereferencing the pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

#### The second pointer

The second pointer, declared as:

```
int* p = new int;
```

*dynamically* allocates an `int`. This means that the lifetime of the object will terminate either at the exit of the program (not sure if the standard actually enforces this, but I'm pretty sure the underlying OS will take back the unused memory once the program is done executing) or when you free it.

This pointer can be dereferenced safely, unless [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) failed to allocate memory (in which case it will throw `std::bad_alloc` or, since C++11, another exception derived from `std::bad_alloc`).

#### Why the second pointer shouldn't be used in most cases

Memory management is an hard topic. The main tip that I can give you, is to avoid `new` and `delete` like a plague. Whenever you can do something in any other standard way, you should prefer it.

For example, in this case, the only reason I can come up with to justify such a technique is to have an optional parameter. You could, and should, [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) instead.